# Android, http: How to upload a file to a site hosted by a shared server?

Tags: java, php, android, networking, http-post

I bought myself a website where it is being hosted on a linux server which shares one IP address using cpanel. The problem that is, now, i want to use this code to upload a file to my site. Everytime i use the site address like www.site, i'll get an exception saying that the URL is malformed. When i use the ip address (since this is a shared server), i can't find my php code since i don't know how to link to my address.

Does anyone... anyone know how to link me to my site, just so i can upload an xml file?? Really need help here.......

Any help would be really appreciated as i have no knowledge in networking stuff.

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = null; 
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    DataInputStream inputStream = null;
    String pathToOurFile = "/data/data/test.send/testsend.txt";
    String urlServer = "http://www.site.com/filefortransfer.php";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";

    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

    try
    {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs & Outputs
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Enable POST method
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    String serverResponseCode = Integer.toString(connection.getResponseCode());
    String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("MediaPlayer", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

On Android it's preferable for more complex HTTP networking to use HttpClient class.

Here is an example of multipart file upload: http://rapidandroid.org/wiki/HttpUpload

Comment: i;ve tried the code and putting in the apache httpcomponents, the client and the core, but i'm getting the The type org.apache.james.mime4j.message.SingleBody cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files at the package area. How do i solve this?  I'm working with the android on eclipse and i've tried looking for a solution but can't get any.

Comment: solved that by adding the org.apache.james.mime4j library into my reference

Comment: a new problem cropped up. The log came out showing me this problem, java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: org.apache.http.entity.mime, and i have the libraries, what's wrong?

Comment: Maybe this post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482674/android-multipart-http-post-does-not-send-the-files-mime-type

Comment: thanks for answering, i've tried the solutions that was shown to me but it's not working also, the error is still the same.