# Sending video/audio file from Android application to wcf service can not able to open

Tags: android, wcf, file-upload, video-streaming

I try to send video file from android to wcf service. Video file get uploaded successfully and size all same in both end but problem is it can't open. For other file it's working fine but not for only video file.

Below is my Android code:

```
      package com.example.filedemo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

public class HttpUpload {

    public static String res;
    public static String response;
    public void myUploadedfile() {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(
                "http://10.160.0.18:85/Service.svc/UploadFile?fileName=vd.mp4");
        /* ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler(); */

        // Indicate that this information comes in parts (text and file)
        MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
                HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

        try {

            // Create a JSON object to be used in the StringBody
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();

            // Add some values
            jsonObj.put("filename", "vd.mp4");

            // Add the JSON "part"
            reqEntity.addPart("entity", new StringBody(jsonObj.toString()));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.v("App", e.getMessage());
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.v("App", e.getMessage());
        }

        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "vd.mp4"));// ,"application/octet-stream");
        reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);

        try {
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);

            // Execute the request "POST"
            HttpResponse httpResp = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

            /*HttpResponse response = null;*/
            // Check the status code, in this case "created"

            Log.v("App", "Created");
            /*if (((HttpResponse) response).getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_CREATED)
            {

            }*/
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

**wcf code**

```
    FileStream fileToupload = new FileStream("D:\\vd.mp4", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

byte[] bytearray = new byte[10000];
int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
do
{
bytesRead = mystream.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
} while (bytesRead > 0);

fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length);
fileToupload.Close();
fileToupload.Dispose();
return "success";
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue is with MIME type.
[Android Multipart HTTP Post does not send the File's MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3482674/android-multipart-http-post-does-not-send-the-files-mime-type)

Try to use the code given for uploadVideo() method in the accepted answer here.
[Android upload video to remote server using HTTP multipart form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11164398/android-upload-video-to-remote-server-using-http-multipart-form-data)